# How to perform search on a nested asymmetric(different number of branch on each level) JSON in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react-native app for android. I have drawn a tree structure from a nested asymmetric JSON, now I want to perform the search on this, I know how to perform the search on a linear data but my JSON is a bit complicated. Here is my JSON format pic:- [JSON Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyDdK.png)
Different branch can have a different number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a general Javascript question, since tree structures like this can appear anywhere. Assuming that this structure is on props, and that you're trying to return the nested object itself, I would probably do something like this.

```
search(value) {
  // search recursively, return value or keep searching
  checkBranch = function(branch) {
    branch.forEach(leaf => {
      if (leaf.id === value) {
        return leaf;
      if (leaf.branch) {
        return checkBranch(leaf.branch);
      }
  });
  //whatever this is called in your props
  checkBranch(this.props.tree)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It has been very useful to me.

Comment: Hey glad to hear it!